# How to use Cardview on api below 21-AndroidX

Tags: java, android, image, cardview

I need to develop an app that compatible with API 16, and the library that I need to design the Image was Cardview, but it doesn't show properly with API below 21, I search this cardview problem on the internet and doesn't find any solution

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/CV_GameIcon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IMG_GameIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what does it mean: *doesn't show properly* ?

Comment: Radius of the image become weird when the cardview implemented into API below 21